# How to subtract many columns on different pandas DataFrames (assuming the columns have the same name)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with different column sizes. however some of those columns have the same name.

How can I subtract the columns which has the same name and keep the others intact on a new dataframe?

Example:
Imagine I have the two dataframes below:

```
data1 = {'Brazil': [1, 2], 'Chile': [3, 4], 'Indonesia': [5, 6], 'China': [7, 8]}
data2 = {'Brazil': [0, 1], 'Chile': [2, 3], 'China': [4, 5]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)
```

How can I get the below result without naming EACH column on the code (I have 53 columns on the original file to be subtracted)

[image: DataFrame Expected Result]

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) with `fill_value=0`:

```
out = (df1.sub(df2, fill_value=0)
          .reindex(columns=df1.columns) # optional: original column order
          .convert_dtypes()             # optional: integer if possible
       )
```

Output:

```
   Brazil  Chile  Indonesia  China
0       1      1          5      3
1       1      1          6      3
```